# Firing particular rule by rule name in drools without using Agenda Filters

Tags: jboss, drools, rules, rule-engine

I read the rule file and add them into my knowledgeBase then I want to fire a particular rule in that knowledgeBase. Is this task possible in current drools version?

Comment: How would you like to "fire a rule"? - You need to have objects (facts) matching the pattern(s) in the rule condition, and if you have that, you can insert them into Working Memory and then the rule will fire. Without such objects, firing a rule will not make sense.

Comment: Imagine my knowledgeBase has 10 rules. An external API will send me the object(eg: person) and rule name(eg: rule_3). I have to return result after evaluating the received person object against "rule_3" only. I don't want to fire other rules on the person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a rule base where rules should be made active dynamically according to some criterion you have several choices.

1. Agenda filter. You say you don't want this, but why?
2. Put the alternative rules into agenda groups. Select the agenda group "group_3" prior to inserting the fact by a call to

```
kieSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup( "group_3" ).setFocus();
```

3. Write your rules to include a "selection" fact, e.g.

```
rule rule_3
when
    Select( rule == "rule_3" )
    Person( ... )
then ... end
```

The Select fact can be inserted along with the data fact but must be retracted after firing the rule.

Comment: Thnx @laune. Can you please explain how my task can be achieved using agenda filters.?